# How to rename or overwrite php function?

Tags: php, runkit

How i can redefine a function in php with runkit?

```
$helloWorld = 'echo "Call require_once";';
runkit_function_redefine('require_once', '$word', $helloWorld);
require_once("abc.php");
```

i seted in php.ini

```
runkit.internal_override=1
```

when i run, it show:

```
Warning: runkit_function_redefine() [function.runkit-function-redefine]: require_once() not found in hhd_debug.php on line 2

Warning: require_once(abc.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in hhd_debug.php on line 3

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'abc.php' (include_path='.;xampp\php\PEAR') in hhd_debug.php on line 3
```

how i can fix it? please help me!

Comment: This is because your path string(`include_path='.;xampp\php\PEAR'`) is erronous

Comment: require_once is probably a language construct (like "unset" and "list") rather than a function, and is probably impossible to overwrite. Why do you want to override it? What are you trying to do? See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php for neat ways of including files

Comment: i am optimal joomla code for social network and economy electronic.
So, i need compare result after optimal (time run and size of it). in joomla include quite more files, so i need assessment each files before and after included

Comment: Neat. So you want to optimise Joomla and ensure it's only loading scripts it uses? Not a Joomla person, but guess this could have troublesome consequences - consider leaving Joomla alone and using an opcode cache http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators

Comment: Use a profiler like xdebug instead of screwing with the language itself, which will skew your results anyway.

Comment: You can go for override_function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) instead if this serves your purpose.

Comment: **deceze** and **Clancy Hood** are correct, require_once not is function, it is statement, so i can't overwrite it. i tried xdebug before, but it not usefull for now. i am going write a class timmer to calculation time run, get all files included, and remove it if it not need for social network and economy electronic. Any other idea for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would guess this doesn't work because `require_once` is a language construct, not a function.
I don't know if there's any other possibility of overriding it, I'd think not.